# Xamarin.Forms shared project vs. Native Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm a bit confused after checking out [this](https://blog.xamarin.com/native-forms-polished-shiny-xamarin-forms-2-5-0/) article on Xamarin Native Forms. I'm currently using Xamarin for a project, that is created as shared project and does not have any platform specific contents. So my pages and business logic are located inside my shared project, android, iOS and UWP projects don't contain additional stuff.

Would I gain any advantages from moving the shared pages to each platforms project as described in the blogpost? This seems kind of unneccessary to me as I'd have the same code in 3 places.

TL;DR:

What are the advantages of using Xamarin Native Forms (see link) vs. shared project regarding code duplication & performance.

Comment: You can take a look at my answer about Difference between Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin Native. On this url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031120/difference-between-xamarin-forms-and-xamarin-cross-platform/44970929#44970929

Comment: @AlmirVuk great post, thanks!

Comment: Nice to hear that post was helpful for you! @Marcel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are confused.
 Native Forms is a relatively new feature that allows you to use Xamarin.Forms with classic / native Xamarin. You can read more about in the link you provided.

Shared Project is a way to share the business logic across the native applications. There are different "Code Sharing Options" that are nicely explained in the [official documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/code-sharing/). Each of this code sharing options has their own advantages and disadvantages. Get familiar with the official documentation and if you still will have questions just ask.

Comment: So, am I right when I say I can create a Xamarin.Android [..] project for platform specific development or Xamarin.Forms for cross platform. Native Forms allows me to use Xamarin.Forms contents in Xamarin.Android [..]. I want to know how this option differs from the one I'm currently using, since I'm developing cross platform and not specifically for Android or iOS.

Comment: There are different approaches that you can use: Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms. https://www.xamarin.com/forms scroll down till "Which Xamarin approach is best for your app?"

Comment: Alright, thank you! I might have been a bit vague with my question but that helped me out.

Comment: Glad to help! It might sound confusing in the beginning but it is very simple. Most of the topics are covered by the official guide so make sure getting familiar with it. Good luck!